# PresentViewController presents the previously selected cell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a strange problem:
When I run my collectionView project and tap on one of the cells the present view controller at first presents nothing, then when I click the back button and select another cell it opens the detailed view of the first selected cell.

Please share your solving methods
Thanks in advance

Here is my code for the segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "photoDetail" {


        var controller: PhotoDetailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PhotoDetailViewController") as PhotoDetailViewController

        // Pass the selectedPhoto to the destination view controller
        controller.selectedPhotoName = selectedPhotoName

        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
}
```

Comment: where is `selectedPhotoName` set? where is the segue triggered? provide more context.

Comment: I also get this error:  Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7fa11a823a50> on <Fortex.CollectionViewController: 0x7fa1184ac4e0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: That answers none of my question - it raises even more.

Comment: selectedPhotoName is set on the PhotoDetailViewController, I don't understand what do you mean by "where is the segue triggered", I am new to xcode

Comment: one note before doing anything else: the segue actually already contains an instantiated view controller that you are actually supposed to transition to. What are you doing here? From where is that method called? have you called a `performSegue`? Or is it just created using IB? You should maybe follow some tutorials before asking for external help, because we cannot help you if you are not familiar with the terminology.